# BigCommerce JavaScript API

Tags: bigcommerce

In BigCommerce, can I access the current customer's record using JavaScript?

I want to change something on the product page based on the customer group that the current customer is in.

Answer (score 1):

there is no JS SDK yet for Bigcommerce. However, because the APIs are restful, you should be able to execute a simple GET request to get a customer's record. The only challenge is that you need to get the customer ID/info when they login to the store and then get their record.

There is an example on Bigcommerce forums on using Javascript to hide pricing for customers who are not logged in.

http://forum.bigcommerce.com/f4/global-variable-for-current-user-s-group-1815/index2.html

This combined with GET request on the customer endpoint (http://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/customers) should get you moving in that direction.

Does this help? Are you looking for a code sample?

Comment: You need authentication (OAuth or Legacy keys) in order to make a successful GET request to customers.

Having your auth credentials in Javascript, that can access your consumer base, among various other exposed endpoints, is not something I would recommend.

Answer (score -1):

Use Javascript or jQuery to do the IF statement.
Then use Ajax to request the data that you want to display to the user.

So to answer your question, directly with Javascript you can't, but combine it with some PHP and then you use the API to do what you would like.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You don't have access to PHP (or any other server-side language for that matter) within the Bigcommerce templating system, so therefore this is impossible.  I have been playing around in my head whether I should make a javascript SDK for Bigcommerce, but I just haven't really found the time yet.

Comment: It's been a while but don't you have access to ruby? Either way you could handle it all in the JS if you worked the RESTful api?